# omnet++: Dynamic channel creation

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to create a channel dynamically in my application:

Here is the Ned file definition:

```
channel CbsdToSasChannel extends ned.DatarateChannel {
      datarate = 10Mbps;
      delay = 100us;
}
```

In my code, where the channel is created I have :

```
 cDatarateChannel *channel = cDatarateChannel::create("CbsdToSasChannel" );
```

However, the parameters of the channel (i.e. datarate and delay ) are not being set as specified in my ned file. How can I pick up the channel definition from my Ned file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There's a cChannelType::find so the process is essentially isomorphic to dynamic creation of modules. Posting answer with the hope it will be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically create a channel, you can create as follows:

```
cDatarateChannel *CbsdToSasChannel = cDatarateChannel::create("CbsdToSasChannel");
CbsdToSasChannel->setDelay(0.001);//1ms
CbsdToSasChannel->setDatarate(10000);//10Mbps
```